# Implementing Google Trusted Stores on EE Site

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, google

I'm trying to implement Google Trusted Stores on my Expression Engine site using Expresso Store addon.

I was able to get the GTS Badge code/part to work, however I can't get the 2nd code/part to work. Here is an example of Google's code:

```
<!-- START Google Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no">

  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">CUSTOMER_EMAIL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-country">CUSTOMER_COUNTRY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-currency">CURRENCY</span>
  <span id="gts-o-total">ORDER_TOTAL</span>
  <span id="gts-o-discounts">ORDER_DISCOUNTS</span>
  <span id="gts-o-shipping-total">ORDER_SHIPPING</span>
  <span id="gts-o-tax-total">ORDER_TAX</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date">ORDER_EST_DELIVERY_DATE</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-preorder">HAS_BACKORDER_PREORDER</span>
  <span id="gts-o-has-digital">HAS_DIGITAL_GOODS</span>
  <!-- end order and merchant information -->

  <!-- start repeated item specific information -->
  <!-- item example: this area repeated for each item in the order -->
  <span class="gts-item">
    <span class="gts-i-name">ITEM_NAME</span>
    <span class="gts-i-price">ITEM_PRICE</span>
    <span class="gts-i-quantity">ITEM_QUANTITY</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ID</span>
    <span class="gts-i-prodsearch-store-id">ITEM_GOOGLE_SHOPPING_ACCOUNT_ID</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end item 1 example -->
  <!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Google Trusted Stores Order -->
```

My question is, how do I pulled the customer email, customer country, etc details into the script. I tried using the Expresso Store tags for the data {order_total} etc, but that didn't work. I also tried that again after placing the Google script inside of my {exp: expresso store loop.

Using EE 2.8.1 and Expresso Store is up-to-date.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This code is on your order success page right?
If so the information will be available within your

```
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_xx}"}
  order info is all here
{/exp:store:orders}
```

loop

For example:

```
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_3}"}
  <span id="gts-o-email">{order_email}</span>
  <span id="gts-o-country">{billing_country_name}</span>
<!-- now show each cart line -->
{items}
  <span class="gts-i-name">{title}</span>
  <span class="gts-i-price">{item_subtotal}</span>
  <span class="gts-i-quantity">{item_qty}</span>
{/items}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

Remember, if you want currency values that are not pre-formatted, just add _val to the end of each variable for a pure number i.e.

```
{item_subtotal} becomes {item_subtotal_val}
```

Comment: Thank you Jos. When I originally tested this, I had Google's Code inside a template and embedded that on the order confirmation page. So, I wonder if the parsing had something to do with it not working the first time. So,can I use the ExpressionEngine tags to pull the data:

<!-- START Google Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;" translate="no">

  <!-- start order and merchant information -->
  <span id="gts-o-id">MERCHANT_ORDER_ID</span>
  <span id="gts-o-email">{order_email}</span>

Comment: Embeds are parsed fairly late on so it's possible the variables had already been written out by the time the embed was included. Try using a snippet instead - these are parsed very early on and might aswell be considered as being part of the page.
Make sure the Google code is inside the `{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_xx}"}` tag pair and that you've replaced the elements in CAPS with the appropriate Store code (like I showed in the example)